# How to solve ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape in Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I downloaded the Inria Aerial Imagery dataset to experiment training a model to extract building footprints using instance segmentation. The training data is 3 band RGB and the mask images are 1 band grayscale (0 and 1). Following some online tutorials I imported the Segmentation Models library and want to run a Unet model with ResNet34 backbone. Since the Y training data is binary I chose binary_crossentropy as the loss function. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import segmentation_models as sm
import glob
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Set directory paths to X and Y training data
Xtrain_path = 'DIRECTORY'
Ytrain_path = 'DIRECTORY'

# Set backbone model and preprocessing instance through segmentation_models
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocessed_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

# Resize the images from (5000,5000) to (1024,1024) for GPU 
# Resize images
def resize2D(directory,x=256,y=256):
    img_array = []
    for path in next(os.walk(directory))[2]:
        img_path = str(directory+'/'+path)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (y,x))
        img_array.append(img)
    img_array = np.array(img_array)
    return img_array

X_train = resize2D(directory=Xtrain_path,x=1024,y=1024)
Y_train = resize2D(directory=Ytrain_path,x=1024,y=1024)

# Preprocess X_train data
X_train = preprocessed_input(X_train)

# Settign up the model framework with backbone model and seeding with imagenet weights
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights="imagenet")

# Compile the model (set configuration) with binary crossentropy because the predictive 
values are binary
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['mse'])
print(model.summary())

# Run the model
run1 = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_split=0.1,batch_size=10,epochs=20,verbose=1)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [16], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 run1 = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_split=0.1,batch_size=10,epochs=20,verbose=1)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file91tyt_pq.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1930, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "C:\Users\admst\anaconda3\envs\RCNN\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5283, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1024, 1024, 1) vs (None, 1024, 1024, 3)).
```

Comment: From the message it seems like your `y_train` has actually 3 values instead of one, are you sure it is a single value and not a vector of 3 elements? Try printing the shape of y_train

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! The shape of Y_train was (1024,1024,3) where the last should have been 1. In my function definition I had it converting all images to RGB and when I ran the function on the Y_train that's what it did! I modified the function to include a grayscale option, fixed the shapes, and it worked! Thank you again!

Comment: your problem is that you are trying to segment your images in RGB (3 channels), but the model is segmenting it using greyscale (1 channel)... if greyscale is fine for you, you can just fix your `Y_train` doing `Y_train = tf.reduce_mean(Y_train, axis=-1, keepdims=True)`